# how to stop publishing kafka producer after x minutes

Tags: python, apache-kafka, tweepy

I am trying to stop publishing the tweets in Kafka producer python script after x minutes.

Below is main code.

I have tried time.sleep(), foo function with terminate(), etc are not working.

Please suggest to run code for x minutes and then stop(sys.exit()).

```
# twitter authorization
auth = OAuthHandler(API_KEY, API_KEY_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET)

# init tweepy
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# init kafka producer
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
                         value_serializer=lambda x: dumps(x).encode('utf-8'),
                         api_version=(0, 10, 1))


# Step 1: Creating a StreamListener: override tweepy.StreamListener to add logic to on_status
class MyStreamListener(tweepy.Stream):
    def on_status(self, tweet):
        length = len(tweet.text.split(' '))
        if (tweet.lang != 'en') or (length <= 10):
            pass
            print("==filtered==")
        else:
            message = {
                "text": tweet.text,
                "created_at": process_time(tweet.created_at),                
            }

            # write to kafka topic
            
            producer.send(topic_name, value=message)
            
            #NEED TO ADD code to publish producer only for 5 minutes and exit()
            
            sys.exit()
            


# Step 2: Creating a Stream
myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth=api.auth, listener=myStreamListener)

# Step 3: Starting a Stream
myStream.filter(track=keywords_to_track)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution really has nothing to do with Kafka.

Track the time you start the listener and when you want it to end.

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class MyStreamListener(tweepy.Stream):
  def __init__(self, stop_at):
      this.stop_at = stop_at

  def on_status(self, tweet):
     if datetime.now() >= stop_at:
        print("Reached time limit!")
        sys.exit()
     else:
         # process the tweet

end = datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=5)

myStreamListener = MyStreamListener(end)
myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth=api.auth, listener=myStreamListener)
```